# Unattended log on for Windows Server 2008 after reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a desktop app running on a Windows Server 2008. I cannot use a Windows Service, because it uses a .Net WebBrowser control, which won't work in a service.
I can add a registry entry which will start this application, when I log in.

But I want Windows to log in, and thus start this application, completely unattended. For example after an update, or maintenance or loss of power. There are some tips on auto log on, but those seem to be for pure convenience for people, to avoid typing in the username and password.

I want the login to happen completely unattended, without humans involved, regardless when the reboot happens. Perhaps in the middle of the night.

**The main purpose:** I need my Windows desktop application to start immediately after the unattended reboot. *How* this this can be achieved is not important, crucial is that this app needs to run, always.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/)?

Comment: I had a brief look at AlwaysUp, but am not sure if it will satisfy my requirements. Anyone here more knowledgeable?

Answer (score 1):

Bit late on this one, but tweakui used to offer auto-login functionality.
it was bought out by microsoft a while back though so not sure if it still does.